# не получается добавить продукт в google developer console

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Не получается добавить продукт в google developer console типа не контролируемого google для многоразовых покупок, есть только подписка и одноразовая покупка контролируемая google. В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так многоразовые "отменили": добавляете одноразовые, а потом делаете им consume и их опять можно покупать. Как-то так

Comment: Из [документации](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html): *Purchased items can be consumed. When consumed, the item reverts to the "unowned" state and can be purchased again from Google Play*. [Здесь](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume) описано подробнее